# Splitting up SQL server dump

Tags: mysql, database, dump

Is there a way how to split up dump of whole database server (with such tables as 'mysql' or 'information_schema') to single databases?

Looking for better way than insert this whole dump and export needed databases...

Need to recover only part of this dump (only single databases)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
awk '/USE `/{i++}{print > "file."i".sql"}' yourFullMysqlDump.sql
```

it'll create file.X.sql for each of the databases

Comment: nice, thanks. But I think this will skip the step `CREATE DATABASE ...`, isn't it?

Comment: @MarekSebera - yes, but you can add it easily.

Answer (score 2):

Dump is a text file, so just open in in text editor and extract the part you need.

Comment: my dump is unfortunately >100 MB in uncompressed version, and in gzipped version I can't obviously edit it.

Comment: 'text file' isn't quite correct, as it can also contain binary data